# JQuery Mobile buttons rendered incorrectly in IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, button, internet-explorer-9

I have a row of JQuery Mobile buttons created on a button click in my webapp.  These buttons render fine in FF and Chrome, but in IE9, they only render as squares (instead of a full sized rectangle) and the text is mostly missing.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="themes" data-role="popup" data-position-to="#layersImg" data-corners="true" data-transition="none" data-theme="b" data-overlay-theme="a">
    <div class="ui-grid-b">
        <div class="ui-block-a">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical">
                    <!--<legend><strong></strong></legend>-->
                    <div style="margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px"> <a id="firstBtn" data-role="button" data-rel="popup" href="#firstCategory">Title</a>
                   /// and so on ....
```

I am using JQuery 1.7 and JQuery Mobile 1.3.0

I only have this problem with IE (as well as some others, see my other posts!)

ANy ideas? Thanks, Jason

Comment: Try updating the jQuery version to the latest one. Maybe the old version is not playing well with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: No lukc...I updated the JQuery and JQuery mobile library references, and I updated Modernizr also...right now my index.html has:
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
...and I am using version 3.2 of the ArcGIS JS API....

Comment: I am also having this probloem in IE9 in the same app:  I am also having this problem on IE9: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15908114/js-based-webapp-basemap-hidden-in-ie9

Answer (score 0):

well, this seemed to do the trick: I just added a class to the fieldset tag:

```
  <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="vertical" class="ui-btn-right">
```

..and now they render as expected..I am still stuck on the other IE9 issue I linked above!